# Domain install rights without domain admin rights

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2012-r2

Firstly, I'm a new Jnr server Technician.

What rights do I need to apply to a user account in order to have our techs to be allowed to install apps on PC's but not be able to logon to servers, yet they still need to be able to reset unlock AD accounts, add to the domain etc.

Our whole environment is on **Windows 10** and **Server 2012 R2**.

**Microsoft** and **Spiceworks** suggests that local admin rights be enabled but with my users even thats dangerous.

We have **2 Generic Accounts** with domain admin rights and suspect **"some"** user is using it to sabotage the environment.

I need to block / control our techs and/or generic accounts to log onto server via RDP.

Comment: change has been implemented as per suggestion below with success. I have also since removed the generic accounts due to the working solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Microsoft and Spiceworks suggests that local admin rights be enabled but with my users even thats dangerous.

You give your techs local admin to the workstations, not the users. If you have a security group with all your techs in it, then you would add that group to the Administrators group on each workstation. You can do this in group policy.

Comment: thanks for the help. i have finally implemented the change and is working 100%

Answer (score 0):

you can via group policy add a security group to the local PC's and make sure that the techs are part of that security group, they could then install apps using the "run as" option on the users PC. Again you can use security groups in AD to allow the techs to have ADUC on their locale machine that they can perform reset's unlock's etc. And making sure that none of these groups have domain admin rights to allow them to RDP to any of the servers. If you do some Googling around this you should get to where you want to be.